# How do I create a zod object with dynamic keys?

Tags: typescript, types, zod

We can create Zod object that validates an object against the keys that are defined in the schema, but I only want to validate if the key is a string not if the key == something

In typescript we can achieve this by using

```
Record<string, string>;
```

But in zod, I tried this one

```
const data = z.object({
  [z.string()]: z.string(),
});
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're looking for [`z.record`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#records) which can be used like:

```js
const data = z.record(z.string(), z.string());
```

Comment: It seems that we can also omit the 2nd. parameter: `const data = z.record(z.string());`

Comment: To be 100% accurate: You can skip the first argument. But in this case it still ends up being `const data = z.record(z.string());`.